# Vue js execute a child function from a parent and get data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I was building a step form and i would like to perform validation and fetch data from my child component.

So i have a step form which ive separated into container(parent) and step1(child)

THe child has form data

IN the child i have

```
<template>
     thre is the form fiedls
</template>
<script>
 data:()=>({
    orderform:{
      first_name:'',
      lastname:''
    }
  }),

methods:{

 submitOrder(){
  this.$validator.validateAll()
     .then(
      (res)=>{
        if(res){
           //pass this.orderform to parent component

         }   

       }
      )

  }


 }
```

Now in the parent

```
<script>
   methods:{

    gotonextStep(){
       //here execute submitOrder function in the child mcomponent
       //am stuck
       //also retrieve order form data here.


    }



    }

</script>
```

How do i execute the function in the child component and retrieve data fom the parent component.

UPDATE ON PARENT STRUCTURE

```
<stepper>
 <v-stepper-content step="1">
         <child-1></child-1>
    <button  @click.native="gotonextStep">Continue</v-btn>
  </v-stepper-content>
  ...other stepper steps
</stepper>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

```
<child-1 ref="child1"></child-1>
```

Then in the parent you can call methods or get data from the child:

```
methods:{
  goToNextStep(){
     // call child method
     let methodResult = this.$refs.child1.someChildMethod()
     // access data properties in the child
     let childData = this.$refs.child1.someChildDataProperty
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CHILD Component**

```
submitOrder(){
  var that = this;
  this.$validator.validateAll()
     .then(
      (res)=>{
        if(res){
           //pass this.orderform to parent component
           that.emit('childValidated',this.orderform);

         }   

       }
      )

  }
```

**Parent Component**

```
<child-component-name @childValidated="gotonextStep"></child-component-name>
```

> methods:{
>
> ```
> gotonextStep(dataFromChild){
>    //here execute submitOrder function
>    //am stuck
>    //also retrieve order form data here.
> }
> } </script>
> ```

Comment: what am trying to do is execute the child component function while am in the parent component. Thanks for the insight on the emit.